# explode ip range and add to mysql

Tags: arrays, ip

I have a little piece of code, which explodes an IP range and then prints out the individual IP addresses which works perfectly,  But now I am struggling to work out how to store each individual IP address in to a mysql database.

Here is the code to explode the range

```
 $range = "91.216.181.0/24";
 $addresses = array();

 @list($ip, $len) = explode('/', $range);

 if (($min = ip2long($ip)) !== false) {
 $max = ($min | (1<<(32-$len))-1);
 for ($i = $min; $i < $max; $i++)
  $addresses[] = long2ip($i);
 }

 print_r($addresses);
```

I have tried to write the code like this:

```
$ip = print_r{$address);
```

hoping that $ip would represent each individual ip address but it doesn't.

OK so i have no tried this,

```
 $result = print_r($addresses, true);
```

now result holds the entire array, but i still need to find a way to split them individually.

So i finally managed to solve the problem, the complete working code is below.

```
   $range = "$ipdata";
   $addresses = array();

   @list($ip, $len) = explode('/', $range);

   if (($min = ip2long($ip)) !== false) {
   $max = ($min | (1<<(32-$len))-1);
   for ($i = $min; $i < $max; $i++)
   $addresses[] = long2ip($i);
   }

    foreach ($addresses as $tmp) {
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code to solve the problem, I have added a foreach to turn the array elements in to individual strings.